# Why "날 좋아하는 거 알아" means "I know you like me"

Tags: phrase-meaning

i know that (알아  = to know...) and (좋아하는 = "favorite/like"), but can someone explain to me all these words in that phrase context? I can't undestand the meaning of 날 and 거...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

날 is a shortened term of 나를(나+를), meaning 'me'. 나 means I, and 를 is attached right after 나 in order to transform the meaning to 'me'. 거 and 것 is the same: roughly means 'thing'. And 을 is omitted - it should be right after 거(것) but there is nothing wrong with omitting 을 since 을 is a postpositional particle(조사) and omitting 조사 is grammatically allowed.

So, a more formal sentence would be "(나는 네가) 나를 좋아하는 것을 알아." which can be 'technically' and formally translated as "I know the thing(fact) that you like me." - leading to a bit more simplified term "I know you like me."

Comment: 알아 in a truly "formal" form would be 압니다.  If you are using 알아 (intimate style aka 반말) you don't really need to use subject, object, or topic markers at all, unless it is an ambiguous situation.

Comment: I meant "official" rather than "being polite", which means if there are no grammatical errors it is okay. And there is no such rule allowing omitting all those only when one uses 반말. You can learn Korean speech levels like 하십시오체, 하오체, 해요체, etc. if you are not aware of it. Both 반말 and 존댓말 are considered "official".

Comment: "official" and "formal" have a very different kind of meaning, IMHO.  When you say "considered official" ....who do you refer to?  Who is considering them official?  Of course 반말 is standard language, and the Korean Language department of the government considers it "correct" ...so you have me pretty confused.

Comment: Well, maybe this is quite a contradictory statement since we are talking in English but this is how the Naver Korean-English Dictionary tells me about the definition of 'formal': http://endic.naver.com/enkrEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=2669cc3d1e654a64b50749d2b6d51a57&query=formal See that '공식적인'?

Comment: This?  I just cut and pasted this from there:  [ADJ] Formal speech or behaviour is very correct and serious rather than relaxed and friendly, and is used especially in official situations.